# How does the below code perform the required function?

Tags: functional-programming, coq, theorem-proving

```coq
Lemma odd_pred2n: forall n : nat, Even.odd n -> {p : nat | n = pred    (Div2.double p)}.

Lemma even_2n : forall n, even n -> {p : nat | n = double p}.

Lemma even_odd_exists_dec:forall n, {p : nat | n = Div2.double p} + {p : nat | n = pred (Div2.double p)}.
Proof. 
 intro n.
 destruct (Even.even_odd_dec n) as [H_parity|H_parity];
 [ left; apply (Div2.even_2n _ H_parity)
 | right; apply (odd_pred2n _ H_parity)].
Defined.

Definition nat_to_Z_i (n:nat) := 
  match even_odd_exists_dec n with
  | inl s => let (k, _) := s in Z_of_nat k
  | inr s => let (k, _) := s in Zopp (Z_of_nat k)
  end.
```

How does this definition define an injection from `nat` to `Z` ? And, what is `inl`, `inr` and what does `let` do here ?

Answer (score 3):

`odd_pred2n` takes a natural and proof that it's odd, and returns the successor of half (rounded down) that odd natural and also proof that the predecessor of the double is the original odd natural.

`even_2n` takes a natural and proof that it's even, and returns half that even natural and also proof that the double is the original even natural.

`even_odd_exists_dec` decides whether a natural is even or odd, returning either half or the successor of half and also proof that double or the predecessor of double is the original.

`nat_to_Z_i` performs the following map.

```
0 -> 0
1 -> - 1
2 -> 1
3 -> - 2
4 -> 2
5 -> - 3
6 -> 3
...
```

`inl` and `inr` are the constructors to `sum`.

```
Print sum.
```

If `s : {x : T | P x}`, then `s = (x, H)` with `x : T` and `H : P x`. `let (x, y) := z in f x y` is equivalent to:

```coq
match z with
| (x, y) => f x y
end.
```

And:

```coq
match even_odd_exists_dec n with
| inl s => let (k, _) := s in Z_of_nat k
| inr s => let (k, _) := s in Zopp (Z_of_nat k)
end.
```

Is equivalent to:

```coq
match even_odd_exists_dec n with
| inl (k, _) => Z_of_nat k
| inr (k, _) => Zopp (Z_of_nat k)
end.
```